# I am trying to find the original index value of the last occurence of each group

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to find the original indices for the last occurrence of groupby groups.

If I have the dataframe given by:

```
data = {
    'Name':['Jack', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Jill', 'Ryan',
            'Ryan','Lilian', 'Jack', 'Jack', 'Jack'],
    'Age': [15, 20, 25, 30, 23, 23, 45, 24, 65, 115]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

I hope to see:

```
0 Jack 15
3 Jill 30
5 Ryan 23
6 Lilian 45
9 Jack 115
```

Tried using `groupby` and `.last()` after the `groupby` but this gets rid of the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to drop duplicates not considering the records which appear latter as a dupe(i think the expected output before editing), you can also do:

```
(df.assign(k=df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum())
  .drop_duplicates(['Name','k'],keep='last'))
```

Or better as @PiR mentions:

```
df[df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift(-1))]
```

---

```
     Name  Age  k
0    Jack   15  1
3    Jill   30  2
5    Ryan   23  3
6  Lilian   45  4
9    Jack  115  5
```

Comment: `df[df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift(-1))]` is so concise and pretty

Answer (score 3):

Can also

```
df.groupby(df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()).cumsum()).tail(1)
```

---

```
     Name  Age
0    Jack   15
3    Jill   30
5    Ryan   23
6  Lilian   45
9    Jack  115
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html):

```
print(df[~df.Name.ne(df.Name.shift()).cumsum().duplicated(keep='last')])
```

**Output**

```
     Name  Age
0    Jack   15
3    Jill   30
5    Ryan   23
6  Lilian   45
9    Jack  115
```